# How to understand that integration equation

Tags: integration

Really noob question, I'm not really comfortable with math..
I have a reading about accelerometers where I can found the following statement:

$$
\sqrt{a^{2}_{x}+a^{2}_{y}+a^{2}_{z}}
$$

that, I can easily do .. x, y and z stands for the tri axis of the accelerometer

but After that they ask to integrate that norm:

$$
\int(\sqrt{a^{2}_{x}+a^{2}_{y}+a^{2}_{z}} )dt
$$

As I understood the integrate is really between to points.. 
I miss the info between which points do I have to do that?
How can I interpret this formula then?

Thanks for the help.

---

Edit:
I'm trying to put more context. The tri axis accelerometer is providing time based data, each measure contain time, a value for x axis, y axis and z axis.
The goal of that integration is to evaluate the vertical velocity.

Comment: Without more context they could be asking for an antiderivative (I'd guess this isn't the case though).  The concept of an antiderivative is that instead of integrating $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ where $a,b$ are fixed, you integrate $F(x) = \int_{x_0}^x f(t)dt$.  Then, by picking the right $x$, you can calculate any integral you need to.  As an example, we have that $\int_a^b f(t)dt = \int_{x_0}^bf(t)dt+\int_{a}^{x_0}f(t)dt = F(b)-F(a)$.

Unfortunately, finding the antiderivative $F$ is generally difficult to do.

Comment: You need some physics . Do you know that acceleration is the derivative of velocity?

Comment: @Mark, thanks for the info, do you have a link where I can try to understand what is antiderivative is?

Comment: @user251257 thanks for the info but it doesn't help me at all. I will plan to have some physics curses :-)

Comment: @bAN you are looking for the velocity and know the acceleration. Thus, you reverse the differentiation by integration ...